# 'handleOptionsChange' is not defined no-undef in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

1. This format works just fine in my previous projects
2. If I comment out `handleOptionChange`, it renders without any error

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { names } from '../Teams/TeamName.js';
    import './PredictionHome.css';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import def from './default.png';

    class PredictionHome extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                input: null,
            }
        }

        handleOptionsChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({
                input: event.target.value
            });
        }

        render() {
            console.log(this.state.name);
            return(
                <div>
                    <div className="split left scrollable">
                        <div className="pb7 centered white">
                            <img src={def} alt="Avatar woman" />
                            <h2>Team Name</h2>
                            <select className='br4 bg-blue' id='select1' value={this.state.option} onChange={this.handleOptionsChange}> 
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='1' >SRH</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='2' >MI</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='3' >CSK</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='4' >KXIP</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='5' >DC</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='6' >RR</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='7' >RCB</option>
                                <option className='bg-white blue' value='8' >KKR</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="split right scrollable">
                        <div className="pb7 centered">
                            <img src={def} alt="Avatar man" />
                            <h2>Team Name</h2>
                            <select className='br4 bg-blue' id='select2' value={this.state.option} onChange={this.handleOptionsChange}>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='1'>SRH</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='2'>MI</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='3'>CSK</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='4'>KXIP</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='5'>DC</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='6'>RR</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='7'>RCB</option>
                                  <option className='bg-white blue' value='8'>KKR</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default PredictionHome;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I got it.
2. Code was fine
3. There was a problem in node dependency tree for
       babel-eslint 9.0.0 and i added .env file to fix it which caused some
       compiling problem

thanks anyway @tarzen chugh for answering

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with handleOptionsChange
I have following observation for your code:-

1) You have created input state variable and setting it inside handleOptionsChange, but you are not using this state variable in jsx.

2) You have bound state variable `option` for **both** select inputs while you are not setting its value inside handleOptionsChange or for the fact anywhere in code.

You should be setting having different state variables for both select inputs and setting their values inside handleOptionsChange change handler.